# SQL use equal and like condition together

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I need to assemble a sql query that only executes LIKE if it doesn't return value in equal

First used equal if there is no value use LIKE

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE name = 'Ferrari Basic' 
OR name LIKE '%Ferrari Basic%' 
LIMIT 1;
```

Expected: Ferrari Basic

Table example

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ferrari Basic Test |
| 2 | Test Ferrari Basic |
| 3 | Ferrari Basic |
| 4 | Test Ferrari Basic Test |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the best match, order your rows by matching quality. You define what this is. In your example the name length may work (the less characters are added to the searched words the better the match):

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE name LIKE '%Ferrari%Basic%' 
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name)
LIMIT 1;
```

But you can of course have a more complicated expression, for which I'd use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE name LIKE '%Ferrari%Basic%' 
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN name = 'Ferrari Basic' THEN 1 -- exact match
       WHEN name LIKE 'Ferrari Basic%' THEN 2 -- exact match at the beginning
       WHEN name LIKE '%Ferrari Basic' THEN 3 -- exact match at the end
       WHEN name LIKE '%Ferrari Basic%' THEN 4 -- exact match in the middle
       ELSE 5 -- there is something between the two search words
  END
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, if you want only the exact match if available and all non-exact matches else, use `DENSE_RANK` (because MySQL's `LIMIT` clause has no option to include ties):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    cars.*,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name = 'Ferrari Basic' DESC) AS rnk
  FROM cars 
  WHERE name LIKE '%Ferrari%Basic%' 
  ORDER BY 
) ranked
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

(This makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. You can of course use a `CASE` expression, if you like that better.)

Comment: The second solution is very slow to find lines with registers. 7 seconds current.

Comment: For searching for substrings inside a string the database needs a full table scan. You can use `EXPLAIN` to check whether MySQL chooses to do so. If very many rows match the search pattern, then sorting all those rows can take quite some time, too. That means it's mainly left to physic here: how many rows allocate how many blocks on the disk, how many processors are there to deal with this, how fast is the disk, ... I'd expect the first query to be almost as slow as the second. The third might take a bit longer, because it is not limited to one result row.

Comment: I don't know your hardware or the size of your data. Seven seconds sounds rather much, though. An alternative may be to use full text search: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2):

Typically text search engines use a scoring system. A very basic implementation of a scoring logic can look like:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT *,
    case when name = 'Ferrari Basic' then 2 else 1 end as score
  FROM cars 
  WHERE name LIKE '%Ferrari Basic%'
) x
order by score desc
LIMIT 1;
```

In this case matches with `=` will score 2 points, while matches with `LIKE` will only score 1 point. Then you select the match with highest score.

Comment: You don't need both conditions in `WHERE`, since the equality is included in all the like matches.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. LOL.

Comment: I like the solution. Find registers is less than 1 second. 
I need to adapt a query for laravel

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the table for all the rows that contain the pattern `'Ferrari Basic'` and in the `ORDER BY` clause move the rows that have `name` equal to `'Ferrari Basic'` (if they exist) at the top to pick the 1st row only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars 
WHERE name LIKE '%Ferrari Basic%'
ORDER BY name = 'Ferrari Basic' DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b70f491c7e7a0cd067677adc0bb23a85).